# Elasticsearch match phrase prefix results

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm using Elasticsearch to build an autocomplete feature for a search app and I'm using the `shingles tokenizer` to create multi-word suggestions and an `edge_ngram token filter` on those tokens.

I have 55 `JSON` documents that I'm indexing, each document has 2 or more fields and 1 of those fields has multiple words separated by spaces.

If I use the ES `match_phrase_prefix query` with the `_all field` enabled, I should be able to get returned matches with just 1 or 2 character inputs? 
I want to use this query because Elastic itself says its a good query to use for "search as you type" behavior.

IS my thinking correct? Just need to make sure I'm on the right track before I put more time into this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, with the shingles analyzer, you should be able to get results from 1 or 2 characters.

Remember to set the custom analyzer on your `_all` field.

Comment: Here is an useful approach if you also want another analyzer for a "did you mean" option.  [link](http://www.bilyachat.com/2015/07/search-like-google-with-elasticsearch.html)

Comment: Zatarain, thanks, just needed someone to check me on my thinking